# PHP code not showing output properly in table

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","we_love_wildlife");
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: ".mysqli_connect_error();
}

$state = $_POST['state'];
$town = $_POST['town'];
$loc = $town.",".$state;

$sql='select vname from vet where vloc like"%$loc"';
$res=mysqli_query($con,$sql);
echo "<table border='1'>
<tr>
<th>Vet clinic Name</th>
</tr>";

if ($res)
{
    while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($res))
    {
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['vname'] . "</td>";
        echo "</tr>";
    }
    echo "<tr><td>Table ends</td></tr>";
    echo "</table>";
}
else
{
    echo "Sorry! No results found with the given specifications!!!";
}
mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Now the problem is that the 1st header row is displayed. Then nothing else is display. I added the Table ends line to check and that is getting displayed. No query is correct and I have some rows to show because the else part is not getting executed. And also executing the same on My SQL gives me 2 records. What is the problem in my code???

This is the output:

```
Vet clinic Name
Table ends
```

In table format

Comment: why `echo $row['vname'];`

Comment: Ya I removed it...
I had added that for testing purpose.

Comment: your query is giving proper result?? Code seems fine for me.

Comment: I think it does not return any result. Try the query in database

Comment: if ($res) ->checks only whether the query runs or not? It doesnot tell about the result.

Comment: Ya I checked in the mysql console also.
This query instead of variable names if I give like "%chennai,tamil nadu" works perfectly.

Output is:mysql> select vname from vet where vloc like"%chennai,tamil nadu";
+------------------+
| vname            |
+------------------+
| Aalok vet clinic |
| Cozy vets        |
+------------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

Comment: var_dump($row) or may be var_dump(mysqli_fetch_array($res))
What are you getting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your quotation marks are backwards. Instead of having

```
$sql='select vname from vet where vloc like"%$loc"';
```

You need

```
$sql="select vname from vet where vloc like '%$loc'";
```

You need the double-quotes on the *outside* of the string. In single-quote-delimited strings, PHP won't process the variable $loc and interprets in as a string literal, not a variable name. From [the manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php):

> When a string is specified in double quotes or with heredoc, variables are parsed within it.

EDIT: I just want to add that this sort of problem is very easy to debug. If you echo the value of the query being sent to the DB, you would see that it's sending the wrong value. In fact, that should be the very first step in your troubleshooting process: echo/var_dump your variables to make sure they have the expected values. Add this to your troubleshooting toolbox.

Answer (score 1):

This code:

```
$row=mysqli_fetch_array($res);
echo $row['vname'];
```

Pops the first record off of your resultset. That leaves only one record left in your resultset. You should remove it.

Comment: No no sorry...
I added that even for testing process...
Even that isn't getting executed.

Comment: Sorry I edited your answer by mistake. Pls update your old answer

Answer (score 0):

Well guys the answer was very simple. The query had to be changed a bit. It went like this.

```
$sql="select * from vet where vloc like '%$loc'";
```

Just changing this line worked. Notice the quotes. That's it. Even I wasn't able to believe when I saw what had worked.

Comment: @Aleatoric So yah..! You were right. I hadn't seen your answer though. I saw it just now.

Answer (score -1):

Here is your problem

```
$loc = $town.",".$state;

$sql='select vname from vet where vloc like"%$loc"';
```

LIKE Clause in sql accepts only one string, But you have two string with comma seperated

Change it to

```
$sql='SELECT vname FROM vet WHERE vloc LIKE "%$town" OR "%$state"';
```

Comment: Did you run the query in database?

Comment: Why do you want like clause, If you are getting exact location means, It is enough -> WHERE vloc IN ("$town","$state")